# Replace specific values in Julia Dataframe column with random value

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

I'm looking for a way to replace values in Dataframe column with random numbers. They should be different in every row where the substitution was performed.

For example replacing `"X"` with random numbers drawn from `100:120` range

```
julia> df = DataFrame(:a=>[1,2,"X","X",5,"X"],)
6×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a   │
│     │ Any │
├─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 1   │
│ 2   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ X   │
│ 4   │ X   │
│ 5   │ 5   │
│ 6   │ X   │

* Replacing X with random values in 100:120 *

julia> df
6×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a   │
│     │ Any │
├─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 1   │
│ 2   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 103 │
│ 4   │ 110 │
│ 5   │ 5   │
│ 6   │ 116 │
```

I've tried using `replace` but `rand` is evaluated before `replace`:

```
julia> replace!(df.a,"X"=> rand(100:120))
julia> df
6×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ a   │
│     │ Any │
├─────┼─────┤
│ 1   │ 1   │
│ 2   │ 2   │
│ 3   │ 115 │
│ 4   │ 115 │
│ 5   │ 5   │
│ 6   │ 115 │
```

Comment: If you can arrange to have `missing` appear instead of `"X"` it would be more Julian. Then, Przemyslaw's one-liner would be: `replace!(x -> @coalesce(x, rand(100:120)), df.a)` which is more readable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A one liner could be:

```
replace!( x-> x=="X" ? rand() : x, df.a)
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively using operation specification syntax:

```
transform!(df, :a => ByRow(a -> a == "X" ? rand() : a)=> :a)
```

or you can do:

```
rand!(view(df.a, df.a .== "X"), Float64)
```

for another in-place approach (but `replace!` will likely be more efficient)